# Dark theme Mantine & Nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js13, app-router, mantine

So i tried to set up a provider for both my own context for theme storing and Mantine provider, but as expected, this context waits for the useEffect to be executed to set a theme for MantineProvider (by default 'dark'). That leads to a problem that we don't have access to localstorage on server and mantine components are dark by default, but after a few moments they become needed color.

```
'use client';
import React, { ReactNode, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';

import { themeMantine } from '@/styles/themeConfig';

import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { MantineProvider, useEmotionCache } from '@mantine/core';

interface IProviders {
  children: ReactNode;
}

type Theme = 'light' | 'dark' | undefined;

type ThemeContextType = {
  theme: Theme;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({
  theme: undefined,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: IProviders) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>('dark');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    setTheme(storedTheme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const root = document.body;
    if (theme !== undefined && root.dataset.theme !== theme) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
      root.dataset.theme = theme;
    }
  }, [theme]);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((prevTheme) => (prevTheme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  };

  const cache = useEmotionCache();
  cache.compat = true;

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${cache.key} ${Object.keys(cache.inserted).join(' ')}`}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: Object.values(cache.inserted).join(' '),
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <MantineProvider theme={{ ...themeMantine, colorScheme: theme }}>
          {children}
        </MantineProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeProvider;

export const useTheme = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};
```

I tried to set default state value to document.body.dataset.theme but as expected, we don't have access to body on server.

Answer (score 0):

From the V7 docs...

By default, the color scheme value is stored in local storage, and its value is saved in state before the component is mounted to avoid flash of inaccurate color scheme. This means that color scheme value can be different on client and server, as server does not have access to local storage and always uses the default value.

If you have server side rendering in your application (for example, if you use Next.js or Remix), then you cannot use colorScheme value in your application to avoid hydration issues. Instead, you can use dark and light mixins from postcss-preset-mantine to generate styles that will hide elements based on color scheme value: